# Custom code for a lost migration file with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

One of my migration file vanished to blue sky ‍♂️ I'm gonna need to rewrite it manually I guess.

This is what I have in schema.rb for that table

```
 +  create_table "collections", force: :cascade do |t|
 +    t.string "title"
 +    t.string "description"
 +    t.bigint "designer_id"
 +    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 +    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 +    t.index ["designer_id"], name: "index_collections_on_designer_id"
 +  end
```

so should my custom migration be as seen below?

```
  def change
    create_table :collections do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :designer_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Should I do anything about **add_index**?

Thank you!

### -----------

**EDITED SOLUTION IDEA**

Instead of creating new file, I'm going to add to an existing migration file. So that code below should do the job, right?

```
class AddSlugToCollections < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :collections do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :designer_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :collections, :designer_id

    add_column :collections, :slug, :string
    add_index :collections, :slug
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, If you want to retain same changes again then you should add index too.

change migration as,

```
  def change
    create_table :collections do |t|
        t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.integer :designer_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :collections, :designer_id
  end
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I updated my question with your suggestion. I'm going to try adding it to an existing migration file. It should be fine I guess.

Answer (score 2):

@ganesh Navale is correct. I want to add one more point in this. If your migration is already run then rename the new migration timestamp with the old migration timestamp. You can get old migration timestamp from `rake db:migrate:status` command.

Comment: Ah love what that command line gives! Thanks! 

Btw, it is so weird that I lost that migration file. I made a scaffold collections, it's working fine on my localhost, but I'm missing that Create Collections and getting error when I try to deploy to digitalocean